# How to keep an element hidden even before document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This must have an answer already but I can't find it.

My `div`, which I want hidden on page load shows up for a fraction of a second until I explicitly hide it in the document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(() => $("#myDiv").hide());
```

Short of not having it and re-creating it (`$.append` / `$.add` ) or making it the same background color as its background to hide it, how do I ensure that it remains hidden on page load?

Comment: add inline CSS to it? or use a CSS that you put on the head tag. Don't wait until the document is ready

Comment: Why don't you hide the element in the HTML markup? Like `<div style="display:none"> ... </div>`

Comment: use css `#myDiv {display: none};`

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you tried `display: none;` on the element in CSS, then make it appear via JS when you're ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could toggle CSS properties on the div. `display: none;` prevents the element from being rendered at all, and `visibility: hidden;` will render it (occupy space for it from the layout), but makes it invisible. When you want to display the element, just remove the property you set.

Comment: Thanks. Was about to do that when I typed the question but didn't want to pollute the HTML and thought there must have been another way keeping things clean. Appears there isn't. Thanks much. Few minutes before I mark this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have div which you want to be hidden at the beginning, what you can do is you can hide it by using CSS property. Here is how you can do it:

1. display: none.
2. visibility:hidden
3. or inline css  can be given (e.g.

Make sure you know difference before using them. Your 'display:none' will completely hide the element whereas in 'visibility:hidden' a blank space will be there always. Since you are talking about page load here it is:

```
window.onload = function() {$(div).hide()});;
```

Use before div
'.' => for class
'#' => for id

Hope this helps!